# ベンダープレフィックスを自動的に付与する方法

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

Visual Studio 2013（+ Web Essentials）でSass（.scss）ファイルを編集しています。

.scssファイルに

```
div.border {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

と書いたらレンダープレフィックスを自動的に付与して、cssに

```
div.border {
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

と出力する方法はありますか？

[こちら](https://www.xenophy.com/sass/2795)に@mixinを使った方法が紹介されていますが、以下のような独自の記法になってしまうため、できれば標準的な書き方で実現できる方法が望ましいです。
（エディタの入力支援機能などを有効利用したいため）

```
div.border {
  @include PropertySetPrefix(border-radius, 10px);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autoprefixerを有効にするのはどうでしょうか？
https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#visual-studio