# Web Essentials のcssチェック内容をカスタマイズする方法

Tags: css, visual-studio

Visual Studio で .cssファイルに

```
div {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

と書いても何も言われないのですが、

```
div {
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

と書くと

> Browser compatibility: Add missing vendor specific properties to 'transition-duration' (-moz-, -o-, -webkit-)

という警告が表示されます。

Web Essentialsを無効にするとこのメッセージは表示されないので、Web Essentialsがチェックしてると思いますが、チェック内容を変更する方法はあるでしょうか？
例えば、[このページ](https://w3g.jp/blog/tools/vendor_prefix_cleaning#transition)に、

> transitionのベンダープレフィックスには-webkit-のベンダー識別子のみ残しておく必要があると言えるでしょう。

と書いてあるので、-moz-, -o- は省略可能とし、 -webkit-のみ必須とする、というようなカスタマイズを行いたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オプションで設定可能です。

コードエディタで右クリックし、`Web Essentials` から `Select browsers...` を選択し

[image: 右クリックメニューからSelect browsers]

ダイアログで対象のブラウザを選択します。

[image: ダイアログ]

その後にWeb Essentialsのvendor prefixの追加を選択すると、対象のブラウザのものだけ追加されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお、Solution Itemsに `WE-browsers.xml` というファイルが追加されていて、そこに選択されたブラウザの情報が保存されていて、チェックも対象のブラウザのものみになるようです。

Comment: 出来ました。  
transition は -webkit-必須、-columns は-webkit-と-moz-必須、というような細かい設定は無理そうですね。

Answer (score 1):

[ベンダープレフィックスを自動的に付与する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2669/%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%98%E4%B8%8E%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)の質問のようにAutoprefixerを有効にするのはどうでしょうか？ https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#visual-studio